# How to add values to a single variable in while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I would like to add the price values to a total_price and echo it.

My code takes values from session and makes a mysql query to take information from database tables. Once I have it, it shows the prices of each row. Now I'm adding a total price, but instead of taking the values of all prices and add them, it takes the values of the last row only. I would like that total_price to add all the values $price.
Here is the code:

```
<?php 
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) { echo "Nothing here";} else {
$whereIn = implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);

$list_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM packages WHERE id IN ($whereIn)"); 
while($run_list = mysqli_fetch_array($list_query)){
$id = $run_list['id'];
    $price = $run_list['package_price'];  
    $title = $run_list['package_title'];  


    $total_price = '';
$total_price += $price ;




echo '<p> Product :',$title,' | Price: ',$price; ?> <a href="add_to_cart/remove_from_cart.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Remove item</a></p> 

<?php 

}?>  

<p> Total Price: <?php echo $total_price;?></p>

<p> <button> Checkout </button></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Move `$total_price = '';` outside the loop... OR do `$price[] = $run_list['package_price'];` then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php. Also you current approach may be open to SQL injections..

Comment: Thanks to all. All your answers are right. After few days of coding, maybe my brain burned out. I don't know how I did miss this very newbie thing. :)

Comment: You should look into use prepared statements, with parameterized queries. If `remove_from_cart.php` SQL acts like this SQL you are going to run into issues.

Comment: No it doesn't have any sql statement in remove_from_cart.php 
I have there only code that removes an array value from the session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `$total_price = '';` over while loop

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right :)  
How didn't I miss it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$total_price = 0;
while($run_list = mysqli_fetch_array($list_query)){
   $price = $run_list['package_price']; 
   $total_price += $price;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$total_price += $price;
```

You are currently resetting `$total_price` each time you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Your total price variable is getting reset on each iteration. Initialise the variable outside of the loop.

```
$total_price = 0;

while($run_list = mysqli_fetch_array($list_query)){
    $id = $run_list['id'];
    $price = $run_list['package_price'];  
    $title = $run_list['package_title'];  
    $total_price += $price ;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_price ='';
while {
$total_price += $price
}
```

Your total_price  eq price every time the loop is iterating